# How to run a multiple module appengine project locally (with gradle)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle

How to you run a multiple module java appengine project locally?  When I try to start the modules separately, I get errors like `java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080`?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was sufficient to start the other modules together with one of the modules.  I modified the `build.gradle` in one of the modules to include:

```
appengine {
    ...
    run {
        services = [projectAsService(project), projectAsService(":othermodule")]
    }
}
```

Then, starting that one module with

```
./gradlew project:appenginerun
```

launched both of them.  The ports that they were running on were reported in the startup logs.

Note: Task Queue requests always seem to be sent to the instance that is started first (the module invoked with appenginerun).  I was able to work around this by just starting the module that I wanted to receive tasks first, but this might be a problem if you want different tasks to go to different modules.